# Only lists 10 blobs of 100 blobs in the Azure Blobstorage

Tags: angular, typescript, azure, azure-blob-storage

In the Azure Blobstorage i have 100 blobs, but I only want to list the first 10 blobs.
how can I do that?

i wrote `{maxResults:1}` doesn't take any effects, it still lists me all blobs.

here is the function:

```
for await (const blob of containerClient.listBlobsFlat( {maxResults: 1} )) {

  
          const blockBlobClient = containerClient.getBlockBlobClient(blob.name);
    
          const downloadBlockBlobResponse = await blockBlobClient.download(0);
          const download = await blobToString(await downloadBlockBlobResponse.blobBody)
     
          allblobs.push(download)
 
        }
        return allblobs
      }
```

Comment: you want to get the last modified 10 blobs?

Comment: yes, you are right! That's want I look for. Adapted to the code above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of returning iterator to *list all the blobs*

```
for await (const blob of containerClient.listBlobsFlat()) {
    console.log(blob.name);
}
```

you could consider to return an iterator to *list the blobs in pages* via `.byPage()` method and then enumerate blobs in first page:

```
let it = containerClient.listBlobsFlat().byPage({ maxPageSize: 10 });  //set page size
let response = await it.next(); // get first page
let segment = response.value.segment;
for (const blob of segment.blobItems) {
    console.log(`${blob.name}`);
}
```

Refer `azure-sdk-for-js` repository [`iterators-blobs.js` example](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/blob/master/sdk/storage/storage-blob/samples/javascript/iterators-blobs.js) for a more details